# What is the angle (in degrees) that a line with slope $m$ makes with the x-axis (x>=0)

Tags: geometry, slope

I have tried this many times, but all I have figured out is that if one line has slope $a$ and another line has slope $b$ then the ratio of the angles made with the y-axis is the same as the ratio of the two numbers.

Comment: Note: I may have added the wrong tag, please correct it if I did

Comment: ```... the same as the ratio between the two numbers``` not true

Comment: I've edited your question. But still your question is not clear. It's not clear whether you are asking a question of making a statement.

Comment: You may have a look at this question which deals approximately with the same problem as yours : <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573072/what-function-will-give-as-output-the-inclination-measured-in-degrees-of-the-tan>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know that the slope of the line through the origin with angle $\theta$ (measured counterclockwise from the positive $x$-axis) is $\tan\theta$?

So the angle corresponding to slope $m$ would be $\tan^{-1}m$, which could be taken to lie in $(-90^{\circ},90^{\circ})$.